# Keep characters in site-link

Tags: php, url, char

I have a dictionary/glossary which translates from one language to another.

When I fill in a certain word in the form, for example:

**Çögek**

After I submit I get this URL:

**/search?q=%C7%F6%FEek%FD**

Is there any way just to have this in the URL:

**/search?q=Çögek**

I think the last one is SEO friendlier... but no idea how to do that...

Comment: What part exactly are you having trouble with? Generating the URLs? Showing them?

Comment: Get variables will be encoded by http for sure ...what you can do is retrieve them and then apply php's urldeocde($_GET['w']) to get your values as they were submitted

Comment: I want the word to stay the same in the URL, not transformed into: %C7%F6%FEek%FD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with my localhost. It works for me.

```
$str    = "Çöşekı";
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
header("location:example.org/word?w=".utf8_encode($str));
exit;
```

In redirected page, use

```
echo utf8_decode($_GET['w']);
```

Try This.

See the Html Part

```
<html>
<head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8"> 
</head>
<form name="" id="" method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" name="w" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: How can I call that header-location thingy as a 'response' on hitting the submit button in a form? Also, $str has to have the value of the inputfield in the form...

Comment: I have edited my answer with the html forms. I have added meta tags hope that it will works for you.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. The encoding is required to make a valid URL.

Instead, decode the value in your receiving code (what platform are you on anyways, URL decoding is usually done automatically for you)

use [`urlencode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [`urldecode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

also see [`rawurldecode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php)

Comment: I know encoding is required, but I'd like to keep the word in the URl as-is instead of something like this: %C7%F6%FEek%FD.

I know this is possible, if you search on Google to words like: 

Ödön Beöthy

You get results as:

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ödön_Beöthy

As you can see, the ö is in the URL without encoding.

I'm using PHP by the way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for SEO friendly url I suggest you have a look at Apache's Mod Rewrite and .htaccess usage.

Comment: I did earlier, couldn't find anything useful. 
Didn't know this was so difficult, like all the websites I have seen just have those special chars like ö, ü, ş, á, et cetera in the URL name, instead of those hexacodes.... I'd like to have that as well.